# ApacheBench gets "Connection reset by peer" from Go server only with "-race" flag

Tags: http, go, apachebench

I have a minimal Go HTTP server (code below). When I start the server with `go run server.go` and then fire off 5000 concurrent requests using

```
ab -c 5000 -n 5000 http://localhost:8080/
```

everything works as expected. However, if I start my server with the race detector flag:

```
go run -race server.go
```

then I get an issue running ApacheBench even with only 1000 concurrent requests:

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)
```

Interestingly, my Go server doesn't crash or print any error messages, and is able to continue receiving new requests. This suggests that the problem is not the Go process running out of memory because of the "-race" burden.

Additional details:

- I'm running Go 1.10 on a Mac
- `ab -V` tells me I'm using Version 2.3 of ab (default shipment with Macbook, and it looks like ab has been dropped from brew).
- If I run ab with the `-r` flag so that it doesn't exit right away, I get the output: `Test aborted after 10 failures`. So it seems like my Go server must be dropping connections rather than queueing them up...

Go server code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("got one\n")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

ulimit settings:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4864
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: What is your systems ulimits set to? `ulimit -a` from the terminal.

Comment: Hey, added these to bottom of question.

Comment: You can't even open 5000 ports at once, what is the point of making 5000 completely concurrent requests? The `-race` flag  slows things down, and limits the number of possible goroutines that can be running, something has to fail in this test.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand why it would be an open file issue. I'm getting an ApacheBench error making 1,000 calls, which is safely below the 4,864 threshold (unless -race for some reason opens up a bunch of extra files?) Also, open file errors show up server-side: `accept tcp [::]:8080: accept: too many open files in system` but not until I get to ~10,000 concurrent requests. As I mentioned I'm not getting any server-side errors when sending 1,000 requests with "-race".